# Best Practices for Microsoft Message Queue and Resource Release

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, message-queue

I would like to know what are your best practices in using and disposing a message queue.  I would also appreciate if there is code especially in the disposing part in order to visualize your concept.  The language is in C# or any .NET language will do.  The queue that is being used is Microsoft Message Queues.

Currently I am encountering an error that our system is low on resources but our hardware 
specs are high in memory and disk space.

The specific error message that I am encountering is: Insufficient resources to perform operation.

Any significant or relevant help on this matter is very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a load-test we ran in a convoi-situation and had the same issue.

To solve this, we increased the machine quota according to [this Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away.aspx)

Comment: Upvote.  Nice link.  I thought that coding is the only way in considering the efficiency of the message queue but there's more.